# Obtener solo la hora de un TimeStamp (JAVA/Android)

Tags: java, android, timestamp

Quisiera saber como puedo obtener solo la hora de un TimeStamp como el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De aqui supongo que si saco unicamente la hora me deberia dar 20:00 PM (no quiero segundos).

He leido por internet tambien que las personas prefieren usar Joda Time sobre las herramientas que ya ofrece Java en su jdk.

Como podria extraer esa informacion?

Comment: como devuelves ese valor ? en formato string ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilizando [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) y el patrón adecuado, en tu caso **yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ** para que con el método **parse** de [DateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) convertir el *java.lang.String* en *java.util.Date*  y después el patrón adecuado **HH:mm**(Hora del día (0-23)) o **h:mm a**(Hora am/pm (1-12) ), para convertir el *java.util.Date* en *java.lang.String* :

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
        Date result;
        try {
            //Aqui se convierte en Date
            result = df.parse("2018-11-20T20:00:00+0000");
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
            System.out.println(sdf.format(result));
            sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
            sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
            System.out.println(sdf.format(result));
            sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
            sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
            System.out.println(sdf.format(result));


        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Este es el resultado:

2018-11-20 20:00:00

20:00

8:00 PM